# What would be the most efficient way to compute aggregated stats real time from a table with a million records which very frequently gets updated?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

We provide e-learning video content to our user's and we have a table where we insert their progress with values such as video number, seconds watched. So based on the number of seconds watched we aggregate the data to get the number of minutes watched by a user in the last X days.

The problem is that we want to show real-time stats on the analytics dashboard but running a query that brings an aggregated result by each user puts a good amount of load on our database, which is already a 4 CPU / 8 GB managed Postgres instance.

I thought of using triggers on every insert, to maintain the aggregated data in a separate table but the insert transactions happen at the start, any pause, and at the end. But we are doubtful how efficient is this approach as these can trigger N number of times which will then has to compute and insert the data in another table. Basically a lot of transactions.

I wanted to know how can we efficiently model our database so that we can compute these things in real-time or close to real-time.

Comment: With such a low-end server, you will have a really hard time to get any decent performance on large scale aggregation queries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's what I suggested to the project manager. What should be the next steps if we want to have these requirements but at the same time with minimal expense? (at least till get more funding)

Comment: I would go with triggers that maintain pre-aggregated tables.

Comment: +1 for the triggers. By the way, my cellphone is more powerful than your database server... Maybe you want to upgrade your instance as well